# Combination Theory Problem: 5 Seats among 5 Persons

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given the following problem:

> There are $5$ persons seated at the counter of a bar. Not being
>   satisfied with the distribution that they have, they decide that
>   everyone will change their places for a different one. How many ways
>   can they do so? Assume that there are only $5$ seats at the counter of
>   the bar.

What do I derive from this?

It appears to me that the possibilities include:

- Everybody change seat.
- One person remain seated and the others
  change.
- Then two persons remain seated then the others change.
- Then three person...

Whether or not this is correct, my understanding of the theory of combinations is rather weak and I would like some assistance in doing so while solving the stated problem.

With this, how do I know when it is Combination from Permutation or Variation (with/without repeatition)?

Comment: When all $5$ people move the answer is $44$ ways. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement ... Consider the cycle shapes for the other cases.

Comment: "*Not being satisfied... they decide that* **everyone** *will change their places for a different one*" suggests to me that we are interested *only* in the situation that *everybody* changes seats, i.e. we are counting derangements which as pointed out by Donald above means the answer will be $!5=44$.  If you wish to derive this result yourself from first principles, consider using inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: "*With this, how do I know when it is Combination from Permutation or Variation...*" I highly discourage limiting yourself to thinking in terms like this.  Take the time to consider what objects you are counting and how you can describe them.  Take the time to consider what it means for some arrangements to be considered "different" and what it means for them to be considered "the same."  All of this can be done *before* applying a label like "combinations" or "permutations" to the problem, and many times neither is even an appropriate label in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everyone is changing their seats, then noone can keep his/her seat so the question is asking the number of derangements. You can find it by using Inclusion-Exclusion Principle as the following:

Let $A_i$ be a rearrangement such that the $i^{th}$ person keeps his/her seat with $1 \le i \le 5$. Then if everyone changes its seat, number of ways of doing an arrangement like this one is $$5!- \bigg|\bigcup_{i=1}^5A_i \bigg|$$ where $$\bigg|\bigcup_{i=1}^5A_i \bigg| = 5|A_1|-10|A_1 \cap A_2|+10|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|-5|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3 \cap A_4|+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5|$$

because $|A_i| = |A_j|$ for all $i,j \in [1,5]$ with $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$. Now notice that

- $|A_1| = 4! = 24$ (One person keeps its place, other four changes)
- $|A_1 \cap A_2| = 3! = 6$ (Two people keeps their place, other three changes)
- $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = 2! = 2$ (Three people keeps their place, other two changes)
- $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = 1! = 1$ (Four people keeps their place, same as all keeps their place)
- $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5| = 0! = 1$ (All keeps their place)

Putting them to the above equation $$\bigg|\bigcup_{i=1}^5A_i \bigg| = 5\cdot 24 - 10 \cdot6 + 10 \cdot 2 - 5 \cdot 1 +1 = 76$$

So in total, there are $5! - 76 = 44$ derangements.

Comment: Where did you get the 5 and 10 values in the first equation?

Comment: $5 = \binom{5}{1} =  \binom{5}{4}$ and $10 = \binom{5}{2}= \binom{5}{3}$. Since $|A_1| = |A_2| = |A_3| = |A_4| = |A_5|$, those coefficients are number of ways of choosing one of the $A_i$ or two of them or three of them, etc. where $1 \le i \le 5$. Because similarly $|A_1 \cap A_2| = |A_1 \cap A_3| = |A_1 \cap A_4| = |A_1 \cap A_5| = |A_2 \cap A_3| = |A_2 \cap A_4| = |A_2 \cap A_5| = |A_3 \cap A_4| = |A_3 \cap A_5| = |A_4 \cap A_5|$. You can think $|A_1 \cap A_2|$ as the representative element for these $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the cycle shapes of the elements of the symmetry group on $5$ elements

For all $5$ people  moving $(abcde)$ gives $24$ ways & $(ab)(cde)$ gives $20$ ways, so $\color{red}{44}$ ways in toto.

For $4$ people moving $(abcd)(e)$ gives $30$ ways & $(ab)(cd)(e)$ gives $15$ ways, so $\color{red}{45}$ ways in toto.

For $3$ people moving $(abc)(d)(e)$ gives $20$ ways, so $\color{red}{20}$ ways in toto.

For $2$ people moving $(ab)(c)(d)(e)$ gives $10$ ways, so $\color{red}{10}$ ways in toto.

Comment: For completion's sake, only one person changing seats cannot happen, and no people changing seats can occur in exactly $1$ way.  It is then worth pointing out that $44+45+20+10+0+1=120=5!$, the total number of permutations of five people in the first place.

Comment: What formula did you use to get those answers?